# Function perfomed by SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am a new learner to SQL,and I couldn't understand what the following queries do:

```
Select to_char(sal ,’$99,999’) salary from emp where ename =’SCOTT’ ;
Select to_date(’07-july-03’,’RM’) from dual ;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option you could have done would be to actually execute those queries and see what they return.

**1st query**: `to_char` formats number (salary *is* a number) so that it is displayed in desired format. In your case, it adds dollar sign in front of it as well as the *thousands* separator.

```
SQL> select sal original_value,
  2        to_char(sal, '$99,999') formatted_value
  3  from emp
  4  where ename = 'SCOTT';

ORIGINAL_VALUE FORMATTE
-------------- --------
          3000   $3,000
```

**2nd query**: `RM` format model returns Roman month (today is April, it is the 4th month in a year, its Roman representation is IV).

```
SQL> select sysdate,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') formatted,
  3         to_char(sysdate, 'RM') roman
  4  from dual;

SYSDATE   FORMATTED  ROMA
--------- ---------- ----
03-APR-22 03.04.2022 IV

SQL>
```

---

Your 2nd query, on the other hand, seems to be *invalid*:

```
SQL> select to_date('03-apr-22', 'RM') your_query from dual;
select to_date('03-apr-22', 'RM') your_query from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00012: Message 12 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA
; arguments: [12]


SQL>
```

---

More about format models in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm).

Comment: Can you tell what does $99,999 do? Does the value here have any significance?

Comment: Just did; have a look.

Comment: If it returned "ERROR at line 1: ...", what do you think? Is it valid or invalid?